# Flask-RESTful specify HTTP methods allowed for specific endpoints

Tags: rest, flask, flask-restful, http-method

Consider that I have two `Resource` classes:

```py
class UserView(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        ...
    def post(self):
        ...
    def put(self, id):
        ...
    def delete(self, id):
        ...


class AnotherUserView(Resource):
    def get(self):
        ...
    def put(self):
        ...
    def delete(self):
        ...


api.add_resource(UserView, '/user/<int:id>')
api.add_resource(AnotherUserView, '/user')
```

Given the code above, the `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE` methods of `UserView` all require a path parameter `id`. Therefore, `UserView` is mapped to the route `/user/<int:id>`. However, the `POST` method does not need the path parameter `id` but is included under the route that provides the param `id`, which will be confusing.

So now, I'm thinking if there is a way to specify which methods are allowed in a specific route (or endpoint), like what we can do with `Flask`: `@app.route('/user/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE']`.

Expected what-I-can-do:

```py
api.add_resource(UserView, '/user/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
api.add_resource(UserView, '/user', methods=['POST'])
api.add_resource(AnotherUserView, '/user', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
```

But this is actually not going to work, as the compiler tells me I'm overwriting view function `UserView`.

I read the doc of `Flask-RESTful` and found `api.add_resource` doesn't have an arg of `methods` that can be used to specify allowed HTTP methods as `app.route` does. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Flask-Restful the class functions `get`, `post` etc correspond to the http methods. If you don't want a particular method for a Resource simply leave it out.

I personally don't find it confusing having the POST method without an `id` in the class.

To get your expected outcome consider adding the desired routes for each resource. E.g.

```
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

class User(Resource):
    def get(self, id=None):
        if id:
            return "specific user"
        else:
            return "list of users"

    def post(self):
        return "post with no id!"

    def delete(self, id=None):
        if id:
            return "deleting user"
        else:
            return "need to specify a user"

api.add_resource(User, '/user', '/user/<int:id>')
```